# Get the last child of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the last child of parent div, every time I press enter a new div created, I want to get the last div of specific parent div.

```
<div id="parentdiv">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code you have written?

Comment: $('#parentdiv').last()??

Comment: Sounds like you are using a textarea editor i.e TinyMCE.

Comment: am working on a chat application on every enter a new message get added

Comment: `$("#parentdiv div:last-child")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery **[`last()`](https://api.jquery.com/last/)** method like following.

```
$('#parentdiv > div').last()
```

**UPDATE:** last `div` of parent `div` having a class `myclass`.

```
$('#parentdiv > div.myclass').last()
```

Comment: I have a scenario get the last div of parent div having a class myclass?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#parentdiv :last-child");
```

You should use last child selector https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/

Comment: get the last child and then get the information from it like what data it contains I.e comments

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use jQuery here, as querySelector in javascript is sufficient to do your job.

```
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('parentdiv');

console.log(parentDiv.querySelector(':last-child'))
```